# How do I create an API in React

Tags: reactjs, api

```js
const listApplications = [
    {
        id: 1, // SandboxId
        asset: {
            "id": 1,
            name: "desc", // Asset Name
            desc: "desc",
            currentVersion: {
                id: 1
            }
        },
        screenshot: {
            id: 1,
            currentVersion: {
                id: 1
            }
        }
    }
];


export default class Sandbox extends React.Component<RouteComponentProps<{}>, {}> {
    public render() {
        return <pre>{JSON.stringify(listApplications, null, 2)}</pre>;
    }
}
```

```js
    componentWillMount() {
        fetch("http://localhost:57833/api/sandbox")
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => console.log(data));
    }
```

I want a component that returns me a hardcoded array in JSON which I can retrieve through an API.

How do I do that?

This is what I have so far.

Sandbox Component is supposed to return me a hardcoded array in JSON which I can access by fetching it.

Comment: Is there a reason why it should be a component and why you want to access it through a URL? React runs in the browser so it won’t respond to server requests and you don’t need to make any to get static data.

Comment: No it can be a URL, but i tought i had to make a component and create a route to acces it @SamiKuhmonen

Comment: If it’s just data you can reference it in your code and it’s there. Just export the object and import it where you need it

Comment: ok but the route has to be from api/sandbox

Comment: Still, why do you need it to have a URL?

Comment: because eventually this data will be real data rendered by a sql query and this is the path where to retreive it

Comment: Then you’ll need to mock it on server side rather than client side

Comment: there is noway to mock it client side ?

Comment: Sure. Don’t try to load from a URL, just get the data from the exported object

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen
evreytime i save the file under /ClientApp/api/applications.json

and enter that url in my fetch i have a 404 error like if the path is incorect

Comment: Yes, it’s incorrect unless you’ve made your server return the data from that URL. You’ll need to fix the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use React for APIs! An API shall be served directly from the server. It can be achieved in a few lines of code. Example in [express](https://expressjs.com/):

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();
const listApplications = [/* your data here*/];
const port = 57833;

app.get('/api/sandbox', (req, res) => {
  res.json(listApplications);
});
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server listening on port ${port}`);
```

Your `fetch('http://localhost:57833/api/sandbox')` will never work, because that is how a React app is served:

1. An .html file is served
2. Your browser parses the file
3. This .html file references one or more .js and possibly some .css, .ico, and other files
4. All files are fetched and served, then runs React's JavaScript code to render the React app
5. **Finally**, the app is rendered, possibly including some JSON **inside the HTML**

And that's the most important point - as a user, you'll might only see the JSON output, but by fetching the file, what is being returned is a very complex HTML+JS object where some JSON is being extracted **only after some heavy browser work**.

TL;DR don't use React for APIs.